# AngularDart ng-repeat in tables?

Tags: html, angularjs, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to iterate over lists with sublists, and printing them as `<tr>` without much success.

This code illustrates what i want to accomplish:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>

  <span ng-repeat='x in [["a1","a2"],["b1","b2"],["c1","c2"]]'>
    <tr>{{x.length}}<tr>
    <span ng-repeat='y in x'>
      <tr>{{y}}<tr>
    </span>
  </span>
</table>
```

I would expect this to show:

```
<table>
  <tr>3</tr>
  <tr>a1</tr>
  <tr>a2</tr>
  <tr>b1</tr>
  // and so on..
</table>
```

what should i do to make this work? I want to be able to repeat without the need to put in spans..

Answer (score 1):

Only table tags (td, th, tr, tbody...) inside of `<table>` tag are shown, you should add ng-repeat to `<tr>`

If you use angular1.2 or higher you can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` tags:

html:

```
<table ng-controller="apiCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat-start="item in foo" ng-init="first=item[0]">
        <td>first: {{ first }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-init="last = item[1]">
        <td>last: {{ last }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
function apiCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.foo = [
        ['one', 'uno'],
        ['two', 'dos'],
        ['three', 'tres']
    ];
}
```

Here is [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a1xqfsdc/)

Here is [fiddle with nested lists](http://jsfiddle.net/t9yjqd6s/1/)

Comment: AngularDart does not have ng-repeat-start

Answer (score 0):

This question is really old and AngularDart has changed a lot in the meantime. We can use the `<ng-container>` tag to apply all kinds of directives to a group of tags which are to be repeated or put under an `*ngIf` and so forth. The `<ng-container>` tag will not appear in the DOM output, but its contents will be there and affected by the specified directive.

```
<table>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let row of matrix">
        <tr>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let value of row">
                <td>{{value}}</td>
            </ng-container>
        <tr>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

When your component.dart has:

```
List<List<int>> get matrix => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];
```